# what is the best way to hide the consumer key and secret in connected app?

Tags: apex, security, connected-apps

I am trying to establish the REST between two Org. I have created the Connected app and decided to go with userName, Password flow.

Now I want to utilize the connected app in the Apex class. So i need to pull all the information from the app [Consumer Key, Secret, UserName, password, endpointUrl] .

What is the best and secure way to keep all the information and retrieve in apex class.?

Comment: The connected app only needs to be in an org you control. Don't put it in other orgs. Don't package it.

Comment: Yes. But is it safe to store the client secret and key in custom settings. I dont see any encrypted field in custom settings.

Comment: Managed package? Typically just hardcoded into codebase. Interested to hear other ideas